# Quarantine SQL Server queries in .net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Alright, we have two database servers, one is owned by us, one owned by a partner. Our partners have been having issues lately that have been causing us numerous sql timeout errors, which takes down our whole system. We'd prefer to limit the time those queries can take to say 20 seconds max, otherwise quit trying and throw the error (which we can catch with a try/catch block).

Couple of questions:

1. Is there a way to set a particular db/connection string to timeout after X seconds?
2. Is this the best way to quarantine that other system? or are there better ways to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to set the connection timeout on ASP.NET or SQLServer? You can't set it in the connectionstring, but you can on the sqlconnection object. Can you post some code?

Comment: I can't post any code. I honestly just thought of setting timeout while writing that question, so I didn't look into it. I'll look into that and update

Comment: Yeah, alright, this was a pretty dumb question. commandTimeout in the connection string will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumb question - commandTimeout in the connection string will suffice for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of issues are best addressed by the SQL Server [Resource Governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx). Resource Governor will limit the amount of memory and CPU a workload can consume. You can split the server into two workloads and allocate 50% to each, so that you and your partner can each consume 50% of the server resources. This is much better than setting a `CommandTimeout` (which has to be set individually for each SqlCommand, setting it on a connection string has no effect) because the command timeout will not only affect both parties (ie. the one abusing the resources *and* the victim) but is also too late: the commandTimeout will only react *after* the server is slow. Besides, a party cans till abuse resources with frequent small commands.

Comment: but if you know a particular query is longrunning, wouldn't it make sense to ask for leniency on _that_ query? Then you don't have to change the default governance

Comment: As I read the OP, it wants no leniency, but intervention instead: aggressive lower commandtimeout to timeout earlier when the server is unresponsive.

Comment: Setting CommandTimeout in the connectionstring will have no effect? Why then is that even an option? I would love to use Resource Governor - but we are on sql 2005. I put a ton of effort trying to get upgraded, but in the end it's easier for us to move to our own systems.

Comment: that's right, it has no effect since *there isn't a `CommandTimeout` option in connection string*. These is only `ConnectTimeout` which has the effect of setting the login timeout, not command timeout. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.connecttimeout.aspx.

Comment: If Resource Governor is not an option, I would consider virtualization, have two VMs and configure resources at VM level. This would work if you can expose the storage directly to the VMs (no databases on VHDs).